# how to add rgb image and rgba image based on opacity value of the rgba image

Tags: image, numpy

lets say one image is shaped (x,y,3) and another (x,y,4). Now depending on whether the value of pixel in the 4th layer is 0 or non zero. I need to replace pixel values in the first image using the following rule.

1. if pixel in the 4th layer is 0 return image has values= value in (x,y,3) at that pixel in the rgb image
2. if non zero return image has value = value in value at that pixel in the rgba image

the return image should have shape (x,y,3)

Comment: This is a nice question. It would be perfect if you provided a minimal example. Something like a pair of 3x4 or so image arrays and an expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
mask = img2[...,3] > 0

new_img = np.where(mask[...,None], img2[...,:3], img1)
```

Also without need for broadcasting:

```
mask = img2[...,3:] > 0

new_img = np.where(mask, img2[...,:3], img1)
```

Comment: as i understand you suggestion, mask will be a boolean array of shape (x,y), correct? Can you pls elaborate how that will map to the values at the same pixel position from wither img1 or img 2?

Comment: @alphason. Give it a try on a minimal example, which you should have provided with your question to begin with. That being said, yes, it's a 2D array.

Comment: @alphason yes. that's correct. And then we use `broadcast` for `np.where`.

Comment: This is an excellent use of `where`. It usually gets plugged into square holes, so to speak.

Comment: Also I noticed that mask= img2[...,3] doesnot work instead mask=img2[....,3:] as rightly mentioned by Quang. Because the returned shape of the mask in the first part is (x,y) and that gives value error whereas [...,3:] returns shape (x,y,1) which works

Comment: Note that the first approach requires you to broadcast `mask` in `np.where`. The second approach doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you effectively want to use the alpha part of the RGBA image as a binary mask. Assuming `A` is the rgb base image and `B` the rgba top image, both represented as numpy arrays:

```
mask = B[:, :, 3] > 0.5  # you can also use another threshold here
A[mask] = B[mask, 0:3]
```

Both images must have the same shape for this.

Alternatively, you can also overlay the second image on top of the first one using the alpha channel instead of using a binary mask:

```
A = (1-B[:,:,3])*A + B[:,:,3]*B[:,:,0:3]
```

Comment: If you use the mask for weights, don't forget to multiply `A` by `1 - B[..., -1]`

Comment: @anroesti beautiful! this breaks it down so well thanks ;))